# Export Grid to Excel in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, web

I'm in the process of upgrading my web app to ExtJS 5.

I would like to add an Export-to-Excel option to grids but the only resource I found is in here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel

My question is.. Anyone tried this approach with Extjs 5? idk but I think this feature is very important, I was expecting it to be a basic feature in the new version.

Comment: If implementing export on client-side is not a must I would highly recommend you doing it on server. In case you are using .NET as your back-end here are the two good options [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) and [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com). If you are using PHP or something else I am quite sure they have their own libraries as well.

Comment: Thank you Aleksei. Would you please let me know why implementing it on client-side is not recommended?

Comment: Well, generating a simple xlsx-file is not a complex task, since the internal representation of the file is XML. But old .xls-files are not. Imagine if you will want to apply some styling afterwards, insert formulas based on additional information that's being stored in the database etc. It adds unnecessary complexity to the client-side which is in many cases just user interface. And what's most important I doubt that there is any JavaScript-library out there that gives you the same level of control and functionality. Anyway it's up to you whether to use client or server to generate excel